# How to override this method using 'where T : Object'

Tags: c#, overriding, type-constraints

I'm trying to override this method but I fail to understand how

```
public virtual TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>() where TUserData : UserData
        {
            LoadTokenCookie(String.Empty);

            if (!IsCurrentUserAuthorized())
            {
                return null;
            }

            string responseText = (OAuthVersion == "1.0")
                            ? ExecuteAuthorizedRequest(HttpMethod.GET, MeGraphEndpoint)
                            : string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccessToken)
                                ? ExecuteWebRequest(HttpMethod.GET, new Uri(MeGraphEndpoint + "?" + "access_token=" + AuthToken), null, String.Empty)
                                : ExecuteWebRequest(HttpMethod.GET, new Uri(MeGraphEndpoint + "?" + AccessToken + "=" + AuthToken), null, String.Empty);
            var user = Json.Deserialize<TUserData>(responseText);
            return user;
        }
```

When I do the following,

```
public override TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>() where TUserData : UserData{


            return new UserData();
        }
```

the compiler throws 
"Constraints for override and explicit interface implementation methods are inherited from the base method, so they cannot be specified directly"

So I assumed that the return type would be inherently understood as UserDat not TUserData but the following argues that the return type is incorrect

```
public override TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>(){


                return new UserData();
            }
```

Comment: Please show your inheriting class

Comment: Are you certain the C# compiler is throwing an exception?

Comment: Is your intention to use CreateCurrentUser<> with multiple types of UserData, or there is only one type that you expect to return from this method call (as your implementation suggests)?

Answer (score 2):

In override method, following works.

```
public override TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>()
{
    return default(TUserData);
}
```

If the compiler allows you to write following code (`UserDataA` is a subclass of `UserData`)

```
public override TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>()
{
    return new UserDataA();
}
```

Then the consumer of this class calls this method as following (`UserDataB` is another subclass of `UserData`)

```
var userDataB = GetCurrentUser<UserDataB>();
```

The consumer is expecting an instance of type `UserDataB`. But the method returns an instance of type `UserDataA`. verything messes up.

So in a generic method, `TUserData` is representing the type you are dealing with. You could only return an instance of this specific type other than any other type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the name you used in the inheriting class. You didn't specify the class, so let me give a couple of examples. If your inheriting class looked like this:

```
public class ABC<T> extends DEF<T> {
```

Then your override function has to use the same T

```
public override TGetCurrentUser<T>() where T: UserData{
```

If you specified a type, then you need to use that type

```
public class ACB extends DEF<SomeUserData> {
    public override SomeUserDataGetCurrentUser<SomeUserData>(){
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to downcast from `UserData` to whatever type `TUserData` will be, which is not allowed. Since you can't overload a method just by changing the return type you can't overload the method. You would have to use a new non-generic method and/or create a conversion method that can convert a `UserData` to a `TUserData`.

Answer (score 0):

`where TUserData : UserData` means that `TUserData` can be `UserData` or any class that inherits from `UserData`.

You are returning `new UserData()` which might not always be possible to cast to `TUserData`.

For example, consider this class that inherits from `UserData`:

```
public class UserData2 : UserData
{

}
```

What happens when you call `GetCurrentUser<UserData2>()`?

The system cannot cast `new UserData()` to `UserData2`.

What you can do is add a constraint that `TUserData` has a parameterless constructor like this:

```
public virtual TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>() where TUserData : UserData, new()
{

}
```

And then form the derived class, you can construct `TUserData` like this:

```
public override TUserData GetCurrentUser<TUserData>()
{
    return new TUserData();
}
```

This means of course that you can call `GetCurrentUser<TUserData>()` for `UserData` derived classes that have parameterless constructors.